# Passing String With Non Digits/Letters Through JSON

Tags: java, javascript, base64

I am passing an encrypted password through json and a querystring. Lets say for examples sake the password is something like: `V0VuDF9ITK+A744HD=`

When I pass the string through json I use `JSON.stringify` to stringify the string so it can be used on server.

```
var request = sb.serverRequest('changePassword', JSON.stringify({username: username, password: credentialsInput.value, original: password}));
request.done(function() {
    var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    if(response.success) {
        console.log('password changed');
    } else {
        setInstructions('That didn\'t work. Please try again.');
    }
    credentialsInput.value = ''; //Clear input
});
```

However when I try to use the password on the server, it has replaced the `+` with a space so the new password will be `V0VuDF9ITK A744HD=` (notice the space in the middle)? How can I pre-parse the string in java so it includes the non letters and digits in the actual string thats passed? It seems to pass the string down to javascript just fine, but i'd prefer to pre-process in java if possible because there are also cases where I will pass the string via querystring.

I use the base64 encoder in java to encrypt so I am not sure if there are any other possibilities that may have to be taken into considering when escaping characters in the string in javascript. It seems `=` gets passed fine. Are there any other characters this encoding type uses that might become a problem?

P.S. I do not actually do any encrypting in javascript, that is all handled on the server, but in this particular instance I need the encrypted password in javascript because I need to compare it server side...I won't get into all the boring details. I will however be passing this encrypted password through a querystring as well which I assume will be faulted by a `+` or an `=`. How would I pass a string like that in a querystring as well?

UPDATE: The encoding algorthm I use to encrypt passwords is as follows. I may have been mistaken on it being only base64. Is this a safe way to secure passwords?

```
public static synchronized String encrypt(String plainText) throws RuntimeException {
    MessageDigest md = null;

    try{
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
    }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }

    try{
        md.update(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }

    byte raw[] = md.digest();
    String hash = (new BASE64Encoder().encode(raw));
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: base64 encoding is not encryption.  This is no more secure than sending the plaintext password.

Comment: What should I be using instead?

Comment: ryandlf, if you need a secure data transmision then you have to use https. I sometimes use base64 encoding only to _blur slightly sensitive data_, but I use real encription (DES, RIJNDAEL ...) When I really need to secure my data (of course: the whole encription/decription proccess must be done on server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a string safe for passing through a URL, use `encodeURIComponent(your_string_here)`

Comment: What about when the string is passed to javascript via querystring?

Comment: Ok great. So when the url is passed from java to javascript. Will I not have problems getting the value from the querystring if there are +'s and ='s etc in the string? Lets say the url is change?pass=A87DF+7RU7=user=foo.